# How to fix the random Heroku H12 error codes

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

The application is on Node JS + Express. I have tested all the endpoints and they're working fine, without exceed the 30 secs limit time.
I'm getting H12 error code randomly after 30 minutes (or near) of constant operation (basically renders and queries). Looking at the logs, it appears that the request are taken by the app but it never gives back the response.
I was searching in forums but I can't find a solution for this issue.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey Erick!
Could you please add more information, logs, errors, code snippet.

Comment: Hi, it throws a H12 Error, marked by Heroku as "Timeout response". I'm kind of sure that my code (2000+ lines) is working fine. It appears that the Heroku's router stops randomly after 30 minutes, because the H12 appears from any endpoint.